# Installing Oracle 11g R2 on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, oracle

I am trying to install Oracle 11g R2 on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit using the "silent" installer.
I am using an `.rsp` file with the process but getting this error:

```
[FATAL] [INS-30501] Automatic Storage Management software
is not configured on this system

CAUSE: Prior to configuring a database to use
Automatic Storage Management (ASM),
you must install and configure Grid Infrastructure,
which includes ASM software.

ACTION: Grid Infrastructure can be installed from the separate installation
media included in your media pack.
Alternatively, it can be downloaded separately from
Electronic Product Delivery (EPD) or the Oracle Technology Network (OTN)
```

*Should I install Automatic Storage Management (ASM) and how? Or should I avoid ASM, also how?*

Answer (score 0):

It's [not impossible](http://tutorialforlinux.com/2014/10/01/how-to-install-oracle-12c-database-for-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-lts-64bit-linux-easy-guide/) to install Oracle on Ubuntu, Oracle is pushing [it's own Linux](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/linux/overview/index.html) very hard by having the Automatic Storage Management built into its OS.

**Some background info:** 
RedHat is trying very hard to keep up, so those are the two Linux Distributions to watch out for when you install Oracle DBM in a production environment.

As MySQL is part of the Oracle family as well, it's receiving more and more of the common architecture, without receiving the performance boost of the commercial product. Oracle clearly wants MySQL to be and stay the "little" brother of Oracle DBM, but with an easy upgrade path to the commercial product.